# Front-Door Adjustment riddle

Tags: causality, backdoor-path

I would have a question on a specific case of the Front-Door Adjustment.
Suppose $T\rightarrow M\rightarrow Y$ and $T\leftarrow C\rightarrow Y$, so $C$ is the confounder and $M$ is the intermediate variable.
Then the Front-Door Adjustment formula is:
$$P(y|do(t)) = \sum_{m}P(m|do(t))P(y|do(m))=\sum_mP(m|t)\sum_{t'}P(y|m,t')P(t').$$
My questions is: is the following right? I get a very strange result in the end, so I think I have done a mistake somewhere but I cannot find it.

Suppose that the causation between $T$ and $M$ is deterministic, that is $M = f(T)$ for some $f$ then if I plug this in the formula above, all the elements of the external sum are zero except for $m=f(t)$ and so I get for $m=f(t)$:
$$P(y|do(t))=\sum_{t'}P(y¦m,t')P(t')=\sum_{t':m=f(t')}P(y¦m,t')P(t')=\sum_{t':m=f(t')}P(y¦m)P(t')=P(y|m)\sum_{t':m=f(t')}P(t').$$
For example, if $f(x)=x$, then $P(y|do(t)) = P(y|m)P(m)=P(y|t)P(t)$, which I think is wrong.

Are the above calculations correct? Thank you!

Comment: If it is a riddle, which it doesn't appear to be IMO, what is the double or hidden meaning?

Comment: At the end I get $P(y|do(t))=P(y|t)P(t)$, does it makes sense to you? Cause to me it does not. I agree that maybe riddle is not the best way to describe it, but the message is that I get something that I cannot explain.